# Generating button_to tag for rails with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a row to an existing table based on rails events using jquery.
This row has rails code in it. Most of my function works but theres is one big issue

```
function addCompanyRow(company) {
  var row_class = 'fav_company_'+company.id;
  $('#current_favorites tr:last').after(
    '<tr class=\"'+ row_class+'\"><td>'+company.id+'</td><td>'+company.symbol+'</td><td>'+company.name+'</td><td>'
    +'<%= button_to remove_favorite_path('+company.id+'), method: :patch, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" do%> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> <% end %>'
    +'</td></tr>'
    ).animate("slow");
}
```

However because of this part

```
'<%= button_to remove_favorite_path('+company.id+'),
```

The html generates with the text company.id instead of the value of the variable

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/favorite/remove/+company.id+" data-remote="true">
```

Is there a way to properly generate button_to with jquery so that the variables value is used instead of the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, exactly as you are attempting.

You can't pass a variable from javascript, *back in time*, as an argument to the ruby code,  which was only executed when the `.erb` template was initially compiled.

I think you'll need to give up on using `button_to` in this way, and solve your problem with a whole different approach.

Obvious possible approaches, without knowing quite what's going on here: don't render this button client-side: instead get its html from the server via ajax.

Or you could do it with JavaScript still, but only derive the base path from rails. Things like this:

```
var buttonPath = '<%= remove_favorite_path %>/' + id;
```

Will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for this, it makes sense!

Comment: Actually, how would I set the button path? Wouldnt i run into the same issue when trying to append the button_path into my html text for the button_to tag? Now it would show 'buttonPath' in the html which would not be valid

Comment: So you need to make your javascript file an erb template by adding .js.erb as its extension. Then, when it is compiled / rendered by rails, <%= remove_favorite_path %> will get evaluated. The key difference is your not passing client-side arguments into the ruby code. You're just putting the output of ruby code into your javascript, once.